# How to rotate a google.maps.LatLngBounds?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to verify if a google.maps.LatLngBounds contains a specific point.
I use a custom overlay like:

```
export class RotateOverlay extends google.maps.OverlayView {
  private _bounds$ = new Subject<google.maps.LatLngBounds>();
  get bounds$(): Observable<google.maps.LatLngBounds> {
    return this._bounds$.asObservable();
  }

  private div: HTMLDivElement;

  constructor(
    private bounds: google.maps.LatLngBounds,
    private image: string,
    private rotation: number,
    private map: google.maps.Map,
    private dragEnabled: boolean = false
  ) {}

onAdd() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
    div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';

    // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = this.image;
    img.style.width = '100%';
    img.style.height = '100%';
    img.style.position = 'absolute';

    div.appendChild(img);
    this.div = div;

    // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
    const panes = this.getPanes();

   
      const sw = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(
        this.bounds.getSouthWest()
      );
      const ne = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(
        this.bounds.getNorthEast()
      );

      const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        this.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(
          new google.maps.Point(sw.x, sw.y)
        ),
        this.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(
          new google.maps.Point(ne.x, ne.y)
        )
      );
      this._bounds$.next(bounds);
      panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
}
draw() {
// We use the south-west and north-east
// coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
// To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
const overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

// Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
// in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
// We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
const sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(
  this.bounds.getSouthWest()
);
const ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(
  this.bounds.getNorthEast()
);

// Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
const div = this.div;
div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
div.style.width = ne.x - sw.x + 'px';
div.style.height = sw.y - ne.y + 'px';
div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + this.rotation + 'deg)';


 }
  }
```

And in the "parent", I use this to verify if my position is in the bounds:

```
this.rotateOverlay.bounds$.subscribe((bounds) => {
   bounds.contains(this.position);
});
```

The image is correctly display. but the bounds$ receive the position of the point without the rotation included.

How could I get the correct LatLngBounds including the rotation inside?

Thanks

EDIT 1:

following the advices in comment, I created a polygon which is display uppon my custom overlay. But the rotation is not applied, here is the code:

```
const sw = this.bounds.getSouthWest();
      const ne = this.bounds.getNorthEast();
      const coordinates = [
        ne,
        { lat: ne.lat(), lng: sw.lng() },
        sw,
        { lat: sw.lat(), lng: ne.lng() },
      ];

      //debugger;
      var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: coordinates,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });
      polygon.setMap(this.map);

      const rotatePolygon = (polygon, angle) => {
        var map = polygon.getMap();
        var prj = map.getProjection();
        var origin = this.bounds.getCenter(); //rotate around first point

        var coords = polygon.getPath().getArray().map((latLng) => {
          var point = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
          var rotatedLatLng = prj.fromPointToLatLng(rotatePoint(point, origin, angle));
          return { lat: rotatedLatLng.lat(), lng: rotatedLatLng.lng() };
        });
        polygon.setPath(coords);
        return coords;
      }

      const rotatePoint = (point, origin, angle) => {
        var angleRad = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
        return {
          x: Math.cos(angleRad) * (point.x - origin.x) - Math.sin(angleRad) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.x,
          y: Math.sin(angleRad) * (point.x - origin.x) + Math.cos(angleRad) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.y
        };
      }
      debugger;
      const coords = rotatePolygon(polygon, this.rotation);
      //polygon.setPath(coords);
      //polygon.setMap(this.map);
      this._polygon$.next(polygon);

      panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
```

and in the parent:

```
this.rotateOverlay.polygon$.subscribe(polygon => {

          this.map.googleMap.addListener("click", (data) => {
            const isInsidePolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(
              data.latLng,
              polygon
            );
            [..]
```

Comment: A bounds can't be rotated, it is defined as a rectangle aligned to the lines of latitude and longitude.  Make a rotated square polygon and use the poly.containsLocation method.

Comment: Bounds are always a rectangle with no rotation and south-west and north-east corners as the reference points. You could get the overlay corners coordinates and use them to create a polygon and pass it to the `containsLocation` of the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#poly).

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look on it :)

Comment: Do you know where I can find information about rotating a polygon?

Comment: Get the image corners position and convert them to coords.

Comment: I think I have found something, need to test it before posting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I was really close in my Edit 1, here is the working solution:

before the constructor:

```
private _polygon$ = new Subject<google.maps.Polygon>();
  get polygon$(): Observable<google.maps.Polygon> {
    return this._polygon$.asObservable();
  }
```

in onAdd function:

```
const sw = this.bounds.getSouthWest();
      const ne = this.bounds.getNorthEast();
      const coordinates = [
        ne,
        { lat: ne.lat(), lng: sw.lng() },
        sw,
        { lat: sw.lat(), lng: ne.lng() },
      ];

      //debugger;
      var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: coordinates,
        strokeColor: 'transparent', // because I dont want to see it
        fillColor: 'transparent', // because I dont want to see it
      });
      polygon.setMap(this.map);

      const rotatePolygon = (polygon, angle) => {
        var map = polygon.getMap();
        var prj = map.getProjection();
        var origin = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(this.bounds.getCenter()); // here was the error in the Edit 1

        var coords = polygon.getPath().getArray().map((latLng) => {
          var point = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
          var rotatedLatLng = prj.fromPointToLatLng(rotatePoint(point, origin, angle));
          return { lat: rotatedLatLng.lat(), lng: rotatedLatLng.lng() };
        });
        polygon.setPath(coords);
      }

      const rotatePoint = (point, origin, angle) => {
        var angleRad = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
        return {
          x: Math.cos(angleRad) * (point.x - origin.x) - Math.sin(angleRad) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.x,
          y: Math.sin(angleRad) * (point.x - origin.x) + Math.cos(angleRad) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.y
        };
      }
      rotatePolygon(polygon, this.rotation);
      this._polygon$.next(polygon);
```

and in the parent, to handle the click on the map and in the polygon:

```
this.rotateOverlay.polygon$.subscribe(polygon => {
        if (this.positionDevice) {
          polygon.addListener("click", (data) => {
           // inside
          });          

          this.map.googleMap.addListener("click", (data) => {
            // outside
          });
        }
      });
```